# How to set Secret name in Helm templates/deployment.yaml?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

How to set Secret name in Helm templates/deployment.yaml? I have this code in templates/deployment.yaml:

```
containers:
  - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
    envFrom:
    - secretRef:
        name: {{ .Values.secretName }}
```

in values.yaml file i have this:

```
envFrom:
- secretRef:
    name: secret1
```

But helm gives error when creating:

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: 1 error occurred:
        * Deployment.apps "release1-chart1" is invalid: spec.template.spec.containers[0].envFrom[0].secretRef.name: Required value
```

Comment: Looks like off-topic, because it's not about programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `values.yaml` file has configuration for how to install the chart; it does not usually contain fragments of Kubernetes YAML.  In your template code you refer to `.Values.secretName`, which means there needs to be a top-level key in `values.yaml` named `secretName`.

```yaml
# templates/deployment.yaml
envFrom:
  - secretRef:
      name: {{ .Values.secretName }}
```

```yaml
# values.yaml
secretName: secret1
```

If the Secret is part of your Helm chart, you might not need to configure its name, so long as the Deployment and the Secret use the same name.

```yaml
# templates/secret.yaml
metadata:
  name: {{ include "mychart.fullname" . }}
```

```yaml
# templates/deployment.yaml
envFrom:
  - secretRef:
      name: {{ include "mychart.fullname" . }}
```

```yaml
# secret name doesn't appear in values.yaml
```